# Изменение стандартного гамбургера в Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Как изменить стандартный гамбургер в Bootstrap 3?

Comment: в css. соответственно  2-й метке... для более точного ответа вопрос поконкретней задавайте.. и ваши попытки решить задачу.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Не совсем ясен ваш вопрос, поэтому сверстал несколько вариантов меню, которые вы сможете применить с бутстрапом:

```css
.spinner-master * {transition:all 0.3s;-webkit-transition:all 0.3s;box-sizing:border-box;}

.spinner-master {position:relative;margin:50px auto;height:50px;width:50px;}

.spinner-master input[type=checkbox] {display:none;}
.spinner-master label {cursor:pointer;position:absolute;z-index:99;height:100%;width:100%;top:10px;left:0;}

.spinner-master .spinner {position:absolute;height:5px;width:100%;background-color:#000;}

.spinner-master .diagonal.part-1 {position:relative;float:left;}
.spinner-master .horizontal {position:relative;float:left;margin-top:6px;}
.spinner-master .diagonal.part-2 {position:relative;float:left;margin-top:6px;}

.spinner-master input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .spinner-spin > .horizontal {opacity: 0;}
.spinner-master input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .spinner-spin > .diagonal.part-1 {transform:rotate(405deg);-webkit-transform:rotate(405deg);margin-top:10px;}
.spinner-master input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .spinner-spin > .diagonal.part-2 {transform:rotate(-405deg);-webkit-transform:rotate(-405deg);margin-top:-16px;}

/*SECOND VERSION*/
.spinner-master2 * {transition:all 0.3s;-webkit-transition:all 0.3s;box-sizing:border-box;}

.spinner-master2 {position:relative;margin:50px auto;height:50px;width:50px;}

.spinner-master2 input[type=checkbox] {display:none;}
.spinner-master2 label {cursor:pointer;position:absolute;z-index:99;height:100%;width:100%;top:10px;left:0;}

.spinner-master2 .spinner2 {position:absolute;height:5px;width:100%;background-color:#000;}

.spinner-master2 .diagonal.part-1 {position:relative;float:left;}
.spinner-master2 .horizontal {position:relative;float:left;margin-top:7px;}
.spinner-master2 .diagonal.part-2 {position:relative;float:left;margin-top:6px;}

.spinner-master2 input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .spinner-spin2 > .horizontal {opacity: 0;}
.spinner-master2 input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .spinner-spin2 > .diagonal.part-1 {transform:rotate(135deg);-webkit-transform:rotate(135deg);margin-top:10px;}
.spinner-master2 input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .spinner-spin2 > .diagonal.part-2 {transform:rotate(-135deg);-webkit-transform:rotate(-135deg);margin-top:-16px;}

/*THIRD VERSION*/
.spinner-master3 * {transition:all 0.3s;-webkit-transition:all 0.3s;box-sizing:border-box;}

.spinner-master3 {position:relative;margin:50px auto;height:50px;width:50px;}

.spinner-master3 input[type=checkbox] {display:none;}
.spinner-master3 label {cursor:pointer;position:absolute;z-index:99;height:100%;width:100%;top:10px;left:0;}

.spinner-master3 .spinner3 {position:absolute;height:5px;width:100%;background-color:#000;}

.spinner-master3 .diagonal.part-1 {position:relative;float:left;}
.spinner-master3 .horizontal {position:relative;float:left;margin-top:6px;}
.spinner-master3 .diagonal.part-2 {position:relative;float:left;margin-top:6px;}

.spinner-master3 input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .spinner-spin3 > .horizontal {transform:scale(2,1);-webkit-transform:scale(2,1); opacity: 0;}
.spinner-master3 input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .spinner-spin3 > .diagonal.part-1 {transform:rotate(-135deg);-webkit-transform:rotate(-135deg);margin-top:10px;}
.spinner-master3 input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .spinner-spin3 > .diagonal.part-2 {transform:rotate(135deg);-webkit-transform:rotate(135deg);margin-top:-16px;}

/*FORTH VERSION*/
.spinner-master4 * {transition:all 0.3s;-webkit-transition:all 0.3s;box-sizing:border-box;}

.spinner-master4 {position:relative;margin:50px auto;height:50px;width:50px;}

.spinner-master4 input[type=checkbox] {display:none;}
.spinner-master4 label {cursor:pointer;position:absolute;z-index:99;height:100%;width:100%;top:10px;left:0;}

.spinner-master4 .spinner4 {position:absolute;height:5px;width:100%;background-color:#000;}

.spinner-master4 .diagonal.part-1 {position:relative;float:left;}
.spinner-master4 .horizontal {position:relative;float:left;margin-top:6px;}
.spinner-master4 .diagonal.part-2 {position:relative;float:left;margin-top:6px;}

.spinner-master4 input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .spinner-spin4 > .horizontal {transform:translate(-100px, 0px);-webkit-transform:translate(-100px, 0px); opacity: 0;}
.spinner-master4 input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .spinner-spin4 > .diagonal.part-1 {transform:rotate(-135deg);-webkit-transform:rotate(-135deg);margin-top:10px;}
.spinner-master4 input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .spinner-spin4 > .diagonal.part-2 {transform:rotate(135deg);-webkit-transform:rotate(135deg);margin-top:-16px;}
```

```html
<div class="spinner-master">
  <input type="checkbox" id="spinner-form" />
  <label for="spinner-form" class="spinner-spin">
<div class="spinner diagonal part-1"></div>
<div class="spinner horizontal"></div>
<div class="spinner diagonal part-2"></div>
  </label>
</div>
<div class="spinner-master2">
  <input type="checkbox" id="spinner-form2" />
  <label for="spinner-form2" class="spinner-spin2">
<div class="spinner2 diagonal part-1"></div>
<div class="spinner2 horizontal"></div>
<div class="spinner2 diagonal part-2"></div>
  </label>
</div>
<div class="spinner-master3">
  <input type="checkbox" id="spinner-form3" />
  <label for="spinner-form3" class="spinner-spin3">
<div class="spinner3 diagonal part-1"></div>
<div class="spinner3 horizontal"></div>
<div class="spinner3 diagonal part-2"></div>
  </label>
</div>
<div class="spinner-master4">
  <input type="checkbox" id="spinner-form4" />
  <label for="spinner-form4" class="spinner-spin4">
<div class="spinner4 diagonal part-1"></div>
<div class="spinner4 horizontal"></div>
<div class="spinner4 diagonal part-2"></div>
  </label>
</div>
```